# Iphone two UIPickerView with different data

Tags: iphone, uipickerview, uipickerviewcontroller

I wanted to display UIPickerView with number percent. But the second UIPickerView show up same percentage numbers. I don't want that.

I want something like this:
http://easyiphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/07/using-two-pickerviews-together.html

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with what the article teaches?

If you don't a instance variable or property of at least one of the pickets you can use tags by setting the pickets tag property to a unique number each

It would be more helpful if you posted some code you have.